# pow (power) template implementation from wiki

Tags: c++, templates, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Template Metaprogramming - Difference Between Using Enum Hack and Static Const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172647/template-metaprogramming-difference-between-using-enum-hack-and-static-const)

please explain what for is `enum` used in following implementation of power template.

```
template<int B, int N>
struct Pow {
    // recursive call and recombination.
    enum{ value = B*Pow<B, N-1>::value };
};

template< int B >
struct Pow<B, 0> {
    // ''N == 0'' condition of termination.
    enum{ value = 1 };
};
int quartic_of_three = Pow<3, 4>::value;
```

I found it on wikipedia. Is there a difference between `int` and `enum` in this case?

Comment: @user - `enum` worked for some old compilers, like Borland C++, which didn't support `static const int`.

Answer (score 6):

There could be a difference if you ever try to take an address of an `static const int`. In that case, the compiler will generate storage for the `static const int`. You can't take the address of an `enum` and the compiler will never generate storage for it.

See also [Template Metaprogramming - Difference Between Using Enum Hack and Static Const](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2172647/819272)

Comment: @user1494506: don't forget the `const`.