# Calculate some values using template size_t param

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

What is the C++ way to calculate some values using template params?

```
template<typename T, size_t SIZE>
class ThreadSafeArray
{
private:
    static const size_t BLOCK_SIZE = SIZE > 32 ? 16 : 4;
    static const size_t MUTEX_COUNT = SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE + 1;
    ...
};
```

or this

```
template<typename T, size_t SIZE>
class ThreadSafeArray
{
private:
    enum
    {
        BLOCK_SIZE = SIZE > 32 ? 16 : 4,
        MUTEX_COUNT = SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE + 1
    };
        ....
};
```

or somehow else?

Comment: In C++, as in most other languages, there is no "one correct way" of doing things.

Comment: I agree with you, both these ways are correct, but I want to know some good practices in this subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **enum hack** is the old way to provide compile-time computations. It was used when *in class initialization* is not supportted by some compilers, so `static const` cannot be used. Nowadays its fixed in all modern compilers. 
So the preferred way is to use `static const`.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2172766/1609356) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The "enum hack" works with really old compilers that don't implement `static const` correctly (mostly pre-standard ones).

Unless you have no choice but to develop for such ancient tools, the `static const` version is clearly preferable.